# How can I count different values stored in one cell in SQL?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a survey, most questions are yes or no answers.  I made one page in `asp.net` and all of the questions are radio buttons and the answers are the same text in the `.net`.

.aspx:

```
asp:RadioButton ID="Money1" runat="server" GroupName="Money" Text="Yes" 
asp:RadioButton ID="Money2" runat="server" GroupName="Money" Text="No"
```

.aspx.cs:

```
 if (Money1.Checked)
                { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Money", Money1.Text)); }

 else if (Money2.Checked)
                { cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Money", Money2.Text)); }
```

SQL Field:

```
Money   nvarchar(50)    Checked
```

### Now everything is ok, and result is stored in the DB as requested.

But I have to make a report and I'm trying to make SQL view count the results of the yes and no questions, specifically, how many people answered yes and no?
As you can see, both results are stored in one cell.

So, what is the correct SQL statement should I use to catch the count of an answer for this different result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Money,
       Count(*)
FROM   [table]
GROUP BY Money
```

A GROUP BY statement will group the results into categories based on the values of the field(s) you give it to group on.
In this example grouping on Money means all instances of Yes will be grouped together and all instances of No will also be grouped together and then counted separately.

It's also worth noting that if you're using Yes/No answers for most questions then a bit field is the most efficient way to store the data in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Run a query from you aspx page, something like

```
Select count(*) from [tablename] where Money='Yes';
Select count(*) from [tablename] where Money='No';
```

First one should return you no. of people answered *Yes* and second on *No* accordingly.